# ¿Cómo podría incrementar un valor de tres en tres una vez que el usuario presiona un botón utilizando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, botón, click

¡Hola! Estoy entrando en el mundo del JavaScript utilizando la librería jQuery y por ahora sé como establecer la funcionalidad de incrementar un valor de uno en uno cuando el usuario presiona un botón utilizando el operador ++, pero quería saber específicamente ¿cómo se podría hacer lo mismo, pero de incrementar el valor de tres en tres por ejemplo? Tengo una idea básica, creo, de lo que podría hacer, pero llevo un tiempo pensando y no me surgió una manera concreta de llevarlo a cabo.

Aquí les dejo lo poco que sé de lo anterior:

```
$("#btnButton").click(countButton);

let click = 0;

function countButton(){
    click = 3;
    click++;

    $("#pButton").html("Result: " + click);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas: `click++` es una abreviación de `click = click + 1`, entonces puedes aplicar el mismo concepto para incrementar `3` siendo `click = click + 3` donde también puedes usar la abreviación `click += 3`

pd: `click++` es una atajo solo para `añadir + 1`.
también puedes usar los otros operadores: `-`, `*`, `/`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

El operador que deberias usar es += N (donde N es el numero que debes incrementar)

Por ejemplo:

```
$("#btnButton").click(countButton);

let click = 0;

function countButton(){
    click+=3;

    $("#pButton").html("Result: " + click);
}
```